# Custom validation depending on another input

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

The idea is very simple. I have two inputs, and I validate them only if both are  touched. At least one has to be different than 0. Where am I going wrong?

**The HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : (myForm.$submitted || myForm.for.$touched) && myForm.for.$invalid }">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="for">For</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input class="form-control" id="for" name="for" ng-model="item.for" ng-required="(some expression)" type="number" one-not-zero="item.against" one-not-zero-touched="myForm.against.$touched"/>
        <div ng-messages="myForm.for.$error" role="alert" ng-show="(myForm.$submitted || myForm.for.$touched) && myForm.for.$invalid">
            <div class="help-block" ng-message="required">
                REQUIRED
            </div>
            <div class="help-block" ng-message="oneNotZero">At least one has to be different than 0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" class="{'has-error' : (myForm.$submitted || myForm.against.$touched) && myForm.against.$invalid }">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="against">Against</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input class="form-control" id="against" name="against" ng-model="item.against" ng-required="(some expression) " type="number" one-not-zero="item.for" one-not-zero-touched="myForm.for.$touched"/>
        <div ng-messages="myForm.against.$error" role="alert" ng-show="(myForm.$submitted || myForm.against.$touched) && myForm.against.$invalid">
            <div class="help-block" ng-message="required">
                REQUIRED
            </div>
            <div class="help-block" ng-message="oneNotZero">At least one has to be different than 0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The Directive**

```
var oneNotZero = function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            oneNotZero: "=",
            oneNotZeroTouched: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.oneNotZero = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                return scope.oneNotZeroTouched ? !((viewValue == 0) && (scope.oneNotZero == 0)) : true;
            };
        }
    };
};

myModule.directive("oneNotZero", oneNotZero);
```

**EDIT:**  I made some progress, changed the code to my latest version, but it doesn't fully work. If I don't make any changes to the values, and just go trough the inputs until I get to the submit button and hit enter, the validation doesn't fire. SHould I `$watch` the changes on the inputs?

Comment: What is not working? Validation or display error messages?

Comment: Both. it doesn't add the class or the display message. I'm working in VS2015 and I while was debugging, I noticed that when the page loads, it enters the directive, but not when I'm typing in the inputs. I had `updateOn: blur`  there but removed it and still nothing

Comment: About messages i suggest using ngMessages.

Comment: I'll switch my errors to ngMessages, but that doesn't change that the directive is not working

Comment: ngMessages does not depend on directives, it's job is to display error messages easy. Please update you question including all the details.

Comment: All the details are there, the HTML that uses the directive, and the directive itself. And as you said, ngMessages has nothing to do with the directive.

Comment: Made some changes to the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will submit the form if at least one field is not 0 else will display an error message.

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
    <input name="for" ng-model="item.for" type="number" required>
    <input name="against" ng-model="item.against" type="number" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    <div ng-show="myForm.$submitted && (item.for == 0 || item.against == 0)">
        At leat one field must be different from 0.
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I know that :) I want to make the directive work, because I have at least 6 more fields in the whole form